# Mysql Temporary Data

Tags: mysql, temporary

We have requirement, where multiple users are keep on asking some aggregate data for monitoring on table which is quite big. I am thinking creating temporary table that could be memory/memchached which would contains aggregate data from this table, so monitoring apps would read from this table avoiding hits from main table, this table will be keep on updating every 30 sec. So what is best option to do this?

Comment: I know this is old, but could you please tell us how did you end up doing it? I am also interested in a similar solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you already encounter performance problems? I wouldn't think about optimizations until they are really necessary. A database is for fetching data so most of the times this is fast enough because the algorithms are good enough to cache relevant data. Especially if you use the correct indexes.

Comment: We are in process of tuning current queries, currently developers are using HSQL which is generating nearly 15 mb/sec (coding problem), we are moving that to SQL queries, Once that is done then we will monitor performance on table, to tune more thinking adding temporary aggregated table.